# Good source to study the Laplace transform.

Tags: laplace-transform, spectral-theory, semigroups

I am studying the theory of semigroups and its links with the spectral theory and the Laplace transform turns out to be the intermediary between the two. Any suggestions for good sources?

Comment: See [this book](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1226.34002).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Good one, thanks.